# Synchronizing data with identity columns between SQL Express Servers using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, synchronization, sql-server-express, identity, n-tier-architecture

I have designed a database whose MDF file will be copied to remote offices, so basically I will have different databases wth the same scheme. However, some tables from these databases will have to contain the same data. First I was happy because I knew it was easy to sync them using RowVersion columns in each table, but then I remembered that primary key columns in these tables (columns named "ID") are also identity columns. So I have no idea on how to synchronize them in way that they are identical. With same IDs and everything. Also I am doing this through Entity Framework, which sits between the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and .NET Framework 4 WCF Service. Any clues?
 Note that this is a one-way sync, remote offices need to replicate these tables from the main database but they are not able to modify them and write changes back.

The original thread was started here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e5f89bac-959c-490a-befc-a80d5aa9a9a5/ but I haven't come to a solution yet. If you take a look at the thread I linked to, you will see that the proposed solution was to attach records from the main DB context to the client DB context and call "ApplyCurrentValues" method to update the client DB. However I have come to conclusion that it would not work at all due to these reasons:

1. Different EntityKey values between data from two contexts. You can't attach a record to a context if that record's EntityKey doesn't correspond with the context. To get past this issue I had to convert the object from mainDB to the object from clientDB using AutoMapper and set the EntityKey manually prior to attaching the record to clientDB context.
2. If you want to add a new record (if one exists in mainDB but not in clientDB) you can't use Attach. If the record you are trying to attach doesn't exist in the store, EF will throw the exception back at you.
3. If you want to add a new record, you must use AddObject, but that implies the EntityKey is generated automatically and you will not have control over the identity column. If you try to set EntityKey manually prior to adding a new record, EF will throw an exception at you.

So, the question is, how can I replicate data from the main DB to the client DB using EntityFramework?

Comment: Why can't you leave primary key without identity at your client side? As it will always be replicated right? Second, you will have to do two step process, always call FirstOrDefault, if returned null then add new or just change properties and save context.

Comment: @AkashKava the goal is to use the identical database definition with identical WCF service running at each remote office, where these remote WCF services would sync the data with the central WCF service. .edmx and .mdf files would have the identical definition across all offices.

Comment: In that case GUID is your best friend, GUID might be unique, even Microsoft uses Row GUID for replication. But even in that case, merging will always require you to first check whether record exists or not.

Comment: @AkashKava I was aware of that, however the primary key, for most of these tables that must be synchronized across offices, has to be in human-memorable format, which GUID is not. Some portions of the application are required to be fast in terms of the least possible user interaction required and that's where the user should be able to input the record ID they memorized instead of browsing records every time.

Comment: Then in order to do that, your Entity Framework must contain primary keys without Identities, and you can create one Identity Service which shall be used by all clients to get a new ID for particular table and IdentityService will be a service which will probably connect to a database which will only store Identities for tables only. Because in distributed computing, your IDs can not be guaranteed to be unique unless they are synchronized by some sort of Identity Service. Other alternative would be to drop EF at client side and try to use Sync Framework, but its really not that easy.

Comment: @AkashKava What's mitigating is that the data to be synchronized is only written by the server, all clients have to do is replicate that data. Thanks for your comment, I will look into your solution and post back. In the meanwhile you could post an answer to this question, maybe with a proposal about how you would implement this IdentityService. The option with SyncFX is out of the question, I tried it and I don't like it - I like to control every bit of sync process so I prefer the self-written sync function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have recently implemented this solution, however our database was simple enough and we had one meta server (we call it meta as it is our server which holds only identities) and we have data servers. We have three data servers doing three way sync. Now originally we only had three servers, but inserting new IDs were problem and we didnt want to use GUID as well because it is not human readable.

So we introduced concept of IdentityServer (we called it MetaServer), which hosts a simple Web Service and simple database, database consists of Tables with only Identities, Hash and LastUpdate, Hash and LastUpdate are used to validate synchronization.

For example, following two tables are there on Meta Server,

```
Tickets
   TicketID (Primary Key,Identity)
   LastUpdate (DateTime)
   Hash (Hash of Ticket)

Tasks
   TaskID (Primary Key, Identity)
   LastUpdate (DateTime)
   Hash (Hash of Task)
```

Now Data Servers will contain Tickets as follow,

```
Tickets
   TicketID (Primary Key)
   Subject
   Message
   ... 
   ...
Tasks
   TaskID (Primary Key) 
   Subject
   Message
   ...
   ...
```

And our Save method on ObjectContext looks like following,

```
Task task = new Task();
task.TaskID = MetaService.GetNewTaskID();


...
...
// following is save method, checking insert or update, as it is used in 
//synchronization, thats why i wrote it like this
void SaveTask(Task task){
   Task copy = ObjectContext.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.TaskID==task.TaskID);
   if(copy==null){
      copy = new Task();
      ObjectContext.Tasks.AddObject(copy);
   }
   CloneData(task,copy);
   ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

To Perform syncing, I would suggest, add a table like this which will Save every Change in Meta Server (Master Server)

```
Changes
  ChangeID
  ChangeType = Insert,Update,Delete
  ChangeTable
  ChangeKey
  ChangeTime
```

Which then every data server can read from Meta Server and update changes...

Comment: This appears to be the only way to perform the sync through EF. I haven't created a separate database to store identities but I did use a service in order to control the ID generating process. The service call enters the static lock, enumerates through records, calculates the new ID, exits the lock and returns the ID. The syncing is the easier part. Thanks for your answer!